# sed regex - matching text between two double quotes when a pattern appears in the line

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

Using batch PHP from linux shell I am trying to replace the license number in a config file below with a different one. The config line in question may not always appear the same but may or may not have spaces, tabs, etc.

Examples:

```
$config['license_number'] = "jfur2e2ev9uhuvcfu";
$config['license_number'] ="jfur2e2ev9uhuvcfu";
$config['license_number']    ="";
$config['license_number']= "jfur2e2ev9uhuvcfu";
$config[ 'license_number' ] = "jfur2e2ev9uhuvcfu";
```

The key is to find any line with "license_number" (or any other text specified) and replace whatever is between the double quotes with the new config parameter.

I would like to use sed so that I can look in all files recursively. I have tried positive lookbehind but I cannot define a fixed length text to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that there is only one occurrence per line:

```
sed '/license_number/s/"\([^"]*\)"/"foo"/' inputfile
```

In Perl, you can use `\K` for variable length positive lookbehinds.

Comment: Perfect Dennis. My hats off to you!

Comment: One more little hitch. I just discovered that some of my values are surrounded by single quotes rather than double quotes. I have learned that I cannot use the backslash to escape the single quote.

Comment: @EricSnyder: If your version of `sed` supports it, you can use octal or hex escapes. Either `sed 's/\o47/foo/` (that's the letter "o" before the "47") or `sed/\x27/foo/` would change a single quote to "foo". If your `sed` doesn't then this would be equivalent: `sed 's/'\''/foo/'`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the meaning of the regular expression?  "\([^"]*\)" is pretty cryptic.

Comment: @emery: In this case, the escaped parentheses are unnecessary, but they create a capture group which could be used to insert the captured portion in a different place in the replacement, for example. The rest means "zero or more (`*`) non-quote characters (`[^"]`). You can find an excellent regular expression reference and tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution can be solved without much regex. Try awk

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="="}/license_number/{$2="\"foo\""}1'  file
$config['license_number'] ="foo"
$config['license_number'] ="foo"
$config['license_number']    ="foo"
$config['license_number']="foo"
$config[ 'license_number' ] ="foo"
```

this says when "license_number" is found,  change to 2nd field to "foo".  The input field  seperator  and output field separator are set to "=".